# PowerShell run Command as different User when Credential Parameter is missing

Tags: powershell, parameters, scope, credentials, group-policy

I need to run a common PowerShell command to trigger a Group Policy Update "gpupdate" on a remote computer out of a workflow.
The workflow runs in a system user context, which do not have the local admin permissions on the clients to force a remote "gpupdate".
For that reason, I import a PowerShell credential secure string with "Import-CliXml" to run that statement in scope of a user which is local admin on the clients.

But, the command I want to use, don't support the native credential parameter. And I need to use a parameter for the remote client.
`Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $client -RandomDelayInMinutes 0`

I tried many approches from the internet, but it won't work for me:

`Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList $ProcessCommand -WorkingDirectory $env:windir -NoNewWindow -PassThru`

`Start-Process powershell.exe -wait -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList "-command &{Start-Process Powershell.exe -argumentlist '$($cmnd)' -verb runas -wait}"`

If I test to send the remote gpupdate out of a PowerShell console started with a user which is local admin on the remote client, it works.

Did anyone has a solution for this problem?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I connect to remote computers using PowerShell to execute commands on those computers I normally run the following. I've left an example of my code for you to use to execute Invoke-GPUpdate

```
#Local Host Computer 
#$RequestingServer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

#Server List From Text File
#$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\servicetest\servers.txt'

#Server List In Script 
$ServerList = 'Computer1','Computer2','Computer3','Computer4'

#Domain Admin Account 
[STRING]$DomainAccountName = (whoami)
[STRING]$DomainAccountName = $DomainAccountName.Split("\")[1]
[STRING]$DomainAccountPassword = "Password01" #Obviously Change Password    
$DomainAccountSecurePassword = $DomainAccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $DomainAccountName, $DomainAccountSecurePassword
                
#Local Server Admin Account
[STRING] $LocalUser = "Administrator" #Obviously Change Account
[STRING] $LocalPassword = "Password01" #Obviously Change Password
$LocalSecurePassword = $LocalPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$LocalCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $LocalUser, $LocalSecurePassword

#If running on multiple computers / servers etc. - - See Lines 5 and 8
ForEach($ComputerName in $ServerList) {

    #Update Windows Something Locally - See Line 2
    #$DomainSession = New-PSSession -Computername $RequestingServer -Credential $DomainCredentials
    
    #Update Windows Something Remotely - See Lines 5 and 8
    $DomainSession = New-PSSession -Computername $ComputerName -Credential $DomainCredentials
        Invoke-Command -Session $DomainSession -ScriptBlock {   
        
        #Some commands need the computername currently using localhost...
        $GPUpdateServer = $Using:ComputerName
        #$GPUpdateServer = $Using:RequestingServer
        
        # enter code of what you plan to do... 
        Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $GPUpdateServer -RandomDelayInMinutes 0
        }
} End of ForEach Statement

#If running on multiple computers / servers etc. - - See Lines 5 and 8
ForEach($ComputerName in $ServerList) {
    
    #Update Windows Something Locally - See Line 2
    #$LocalSession = New-PSSession -Computername $RequestingServer -Credential $LocalCredentials
    
    #Update Windows Something Remotely - See Lines 5 and 8
    $LocalSession = New-PSSession -Computername $ComputerName -Credential $LocalCredentials
        Invoke-Command -Session $LocalSession -ScriptBlock {
        
        #Some commands need the computername currently using localhost...
        $GPUpdateServer = $Using:ComputerName
        #$GPUpdateServer = $Using:RequestingServer
        
        # enter code of what you plan to do... 
        Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $GPUpdateServer -RandomDelayInMinutes 0
        }
        
} End of ForEach Statement
```

Comment: Hi Neo, I will try this approach, but this requires Windows Remote Management enabled on all client to process PowerShell Remoting to each of them with ```New-PS-Session```. Not exactly what I first want to deploy by GPO.

Answer (score 1):

Facing this problem more in detail, I tested the approach above with the remote PowerShell session. This needs some more preparation in domain for deploying all necessary GPO settings to all clients to make WinRM work.

The remote PowerShell approach works, but I found out that the `Invoke-GPUpdate` command is only available on clients which have RSAT installed. So only works on a few in clients in IT department.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -Computername $clientname -Credential $domainAccountWithLocalAdminRights
```

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $env:ComputerName -RandomDelayInMinutes 0 }
```

```
$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

I switched over to a different approach which worked for me without using remote PS sessions. Completely silent on the client, you will find the triggered gpupdates only in Windows event viewer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $clientname -ScriptBlock { gpupdate } -Credential $domainAccountWithLocalAdminRights
```